# Resultados Jmeter

Tags: testes, jmeter, teste-de-carga

Necessito da ajuda de alguém para entender a conta que jmeter faz para cada resultado mostrado como: "Amostra, Tempo de Inicio, Número de Usuário Virtual, Rótulo, Tempo de Amostra(ms), Estado, Bytes, Sent Bytes, Latency, Connect Time", agradeço quem puder ajudar...[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]